# in PHP using xPath: loadXml not properly inserting text

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to use Xpath to replace an `<a>` tag in a block of HTML. I serach for the `<a>` tags, pull them out, modify them, and re-insert them.

Below is my code:

```
    $html_fragment = '<div class="someclass">... A bunch of HTML content ...</div>'
    $esp_dom = new DOMDocument();
    $esp_dom->formatOutput = false;
    $esp_dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $esp_dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $esp_dom->validateOnParse = false;
    $esp_dom->loadHTML($html_fragment);

    $esp_xpath = new DOMXPath($esp_dom);
    $esp_anchors = $esp_xpath->query('//a');
    $esp_anchor_count = $esp_anchors->length;

    if ($esp_anchor_count > 0){
        for ($z=$esp_anchor_count; $z>0; --$z){
            $esp_anchor = $esp_anchors->item($z-1);

            $esp_anchor_fragment = $esp_dom->saveHTML($esp_anchor);
            $esp_anchor_fragment = dom_savehtml_cleanup($esp_anchor_fragment);


            $esp_anchor_new = $esp_anchor_fragment.'<!--DPM: New Comment After Tag -->';

        /* !!! At this point $esp_anchor is the HTML of the original fragment !!! */
        /* !!! At this point $esp_anchor_new is the correct HTML I want to replace the original node !!! */
            $esp_anchor_code = $esp_dom->createDocumentFragment();
            $esp_anchor_code->appendXML($esp_anchor_new);
            $esp_anchor->parentNode->replaceChild($esp_anchor_code, $esp_anchor);
        /* !!! NOW at this point $esp_anchor is completely empty !!! */

        }
    }


    function dom_savehtml_cleanup($html){
      $html = trim(str_replace('@nbsp;', '&nbsp;', $html));
      $html = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', '', $html);
      return $html;
    }
```

Just as a side-note, when I start with `loadHTML` I am able to get the HTML to load into the dom. I cannot use `loadXML` since it sees errors in the HTML and fails to load properly.

Any ideas why `replaceChild` is making the node empty. Thanks again.

---

EDIT: Below is the HTML I'm storing in `$html_fragment`. It's passed in as a parameter in the live code but that's what that variable contains.

The result of what I'm getting is completely empty Document Fragment. Nothing returns as far as what I can tell.

```
  <div class="sp_content_item sp_content_item type_insert_headline type_standard_orientation sp_text_align_left has_impression_region" data-additional_padding="0" data-columns="1" data-column_padding="0" data-container_width="686" data-orientation_type="standard_orientation" data-orientation_type_name="" data-align="left" data-tracking_esp="omeda" data-impressionregion="TE5URVNU|TExMTENDQw==|THVjaW91cyBW|THVrZSBDYWdl">
    <table class="sp_layout_headline" id="post-dc2558524822540c332fba8e6162d2b9" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="item_separator" style="padding-bottom:25px"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="sp_text_headline_wrapper" style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="sp_text_headline" style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;background-color:transparent"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="sp_text_title sp_text_headline_title" style="text-align:left;color:#222222;font-size:30px;font-family:Arial , Helvetica , sans-serif;font-weight:bold;line-height:1.2em;padding-bottom:3px"><a href="" target="_blank" class="sp_text_title_text" style="color:#222222;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal">Title Of The Item</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="sp_text_description sp_text_headline_desc" style="text-align:left;color:#555555;font-size:16px;font-family:Arial , Helvetica , sans-serif;line-height:1.2em;padding-bottom:5px;font-weight:normal">Description - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: It seems to work as expected, can you update the HTML your testing with and the result your getting.

Comment: Just added the HTML. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Can you add `echo $esp_dom->saveHTML($esp_dom->getElementsByTagName("div")[0]);` at the end of the code and see if this gives you anything?

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay, I figured out the issue but don't have a solution. The problem is `appendXML($esp_anchor_new)` doesn't evaluate as proper XML and breaks, is there a more generalized function or way to do this? Sadly `appendHTML` is not a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short `appendXML` was failing because the HTML was invalid XML...

As a result I set unique strings and replace those strings after the render, such as:

```
    $esp_fragment_array = []
    $esp_fragment_count = 0

    // Add HTML to an array to insert later. Will fail on the appendXML function otherwise
    $esp_fragment_array[$esp_fragment_count] = $esp_anchor_code ;
    $esp_fragment_placeholder = 'esp_tracking_placeholder_'.$esp_fragment_count;
    $esp_fragment_count++;

    ...

    // After processing, replace strings
    for ($i=0; $i<$esp_fragment_count; $i++){
      $haystack = str_replace("esp_tracking_placeholder_$i", $esp_fragment_array[$i], $haystack);
    }
```